# Unable to detect 403 status code in jquery AJAX call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using the following code to invoke an application on another users machine on port 9084 (for the lack of a DEV server). This is a JAVA application that I would like to call from my ASP.Net application (it uses master pages). I would like to call the URL below which will return a 403 error status and a session ID in a cookie. I would like to use this session ID and make another call using an application ID and password.

When I use the URL "http:fwdslash fwdslash machinename:9084 fwdslash PropertyInsuranceDB fwdslash propertyAssociation fwdslash ajax fwdslash getPolicyAddress fwdslash H0271812 fwdslash 08" in the browser, I get the HTTP 403 Forbidden error page. When I try the code as below, I see the same in Fiddler, but I am not able to trap it in the error section of the ajax call below.

What could I be doing wrong? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
$.ajax({   url: "http://machinename:9084/PropertyInsuranceDB/propertyAssociation/ajax/getPolicyAddress/H0271812/08",
            context : document.body,
            type: "get",
            success: function (data, status) {
                alert(status);
            },
            error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(desc);
                alert(err);
            }
        });
```

Thanks

--Nivedita

Comment: Can you share what you do get when you run your code above?

Comment: @Matt Pileggi, Nothing happened. I was expecting the error function to be executed. Then I set async to false on a hunch, and it started working.

Answer (score 6):

If the server returns something, it's usually considered a successful ajax call, even if it doesn't return what you want it to return.

To catch the status codes you can do

```
    $.ajax({
     url: "YOURURLHERE",
     context: document.body,
     type: "get",
     statusCode: {
         403: function (xhr) {
             console.log('403 response');
         }
     },
     success: function (data, status) {
         alert(status);
     },
     error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
         alert(xhr.status);
         alert(desc);
         alert(err);
     }
 });
```

Comment: I added the statusCode as you suggested, and also set async to false on a hunch, and I am now able to trap the 403 status code / error. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it globally, jquery gives and API for it ([docs here](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)). Some people suggest changing the default configuration with ajaxSetup, but [jquery discourages it](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/). So the preferred method is like this one:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {

        if(xhr.status == 403){//unauthorized calls
            // do whatever want with the event ie:
            //event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            //show a global UI for ajax login again
            console.error('403 response');
        }

});
```