# Ajax callbacks not triggered when HTTP status code is 403

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to use `AJAX` to retrieve the `HTML status code` for a cross origin domain name within my script. All I really care about with regards to the  `jqXHR` object is the `status` and `statusText` keys. It works great for ever type of status code with the exception of the `403 (Forbidden)`.

Unfortunately I can not provide the domain itself, nor have I been able to find a test domain to return a 403.

When the domain returns a `403` it displays the following in the console but nothing else is sent to the console.

```
GET http://THEDOMAIN/?callback=jQuery110102736124559305608_1398894659852&_=1398894659853 403 (Forbidden)
```

As it is a `Cross-Domain` request I use `jsonp` which works great for every other status code returned to me.

**JQuery 1.10.1**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://google.com", // Replace with 403 domain.
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    //async: false,
    //type: "get",
    statusCode: {
        403: function (xhr) {
            console.log('403 response');
        }
    },
    success: function (data, status) {
        alert(status);
    },
    error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
        alert(xhr.status);
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ah6vd/)**

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106522/unable-to-detect-403-status-code-in-jquery-ajax-call) and setting `async: false` did not work, and Google has not been much help with this one.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When selecting jQuery 2.x the error callback is called, but the response code is 404 and not the actual 403.

Internally jQuery uses a `<script />` element to do cross domain talk, it checks for `load` and `readystatechange` events, neither is triggered when loading a script fails with 403.

With jQuery 2.x the events `load` and `error` are used. In case of 403 an error event is triggered, but there is no information about the actual error (or the HTML response code), so jQuery does the following.

```js
.on( 
    "load error",
    callback = function( evt ) {
    script.remove();
    callback = null;
    if ( evt ) {
        complete( evt.type === "error" ? 404 : 200, evt.type );
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I saw the same thing under the hood a little while after asking. Unfortunately it is not going to work, but I should have known better the to attempt it client-side. Server-side checking for this is DEFINITELY the better way to do it. Thanks again.